# Trouble setting up a basic template cards with Facebook Messenger

Tags: javascript, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

New to dialogflow.

I have integrated my agent into facebook messenger, where it can 'talk' via the basic intent/response setup. I deployed my agent using Dialogflow's Inline Editor, in which, I haven't made any changes to index.js and package.json files that the editor provides as boilerplate.

**The problem:**
I'm trying to implement a rich message, such as a [list template card](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/list). Dialogflow has an option of selecting a template from its respective tab (see image below):

[image]

After this setup, when I type the user command that triggers the intent where the card should be the response, I get the following message: *"This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!"*

I suspect I am missing a very key step(s) to this setup as I'm only adding the response. Unfortunately I have not found any clear/helpful docs that can explain step by step how to implement this or any template. Would appreciate an explicit path as to how this can get implemented.

Comment: uncheck the "use webhook" checkbox for the responses you've defined inside Dialogflow's console to be surfaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable `use webhook`, you won't get responses from `Response tab` in dialoagflow dashboard. you will have to explicitly develop cards in your webhook/inline editor & then send it back to user. At any point in time, if your webhook call fails then only bot will send default responses that you have added as message content in your dashboard.

As in your case, you haven't defined your intent & response in code here, you're getting highlighted default response.

[image]

So, if you don't want to code, disable `use webhook` option & see, you will get card as a response as shown in following snap.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned Ive done this step. And I have been testing on the fbook messenger app. Am I supposed to be adding anything additional to the webook/editor?

Comment: @kode_12 No, you didn't get my point. Please read my answer again. The intent that you want to trigger has use webhook option enabled, so you will recieve answer from webhook/inline editor (which you're getting). If you want card as a response, please disable (uncheck) use webhook option which is right there at the footer side of an intent.